# Henselization and completions of local rings & schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

That's the second part of my course  [becoming acquainted with Henselizations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354591/henselian-valued-fields-for-characteristic-0-a-chacterization) of fields and local rings. (in this question we focus on local rings as it is more algebro geometric motivated). So let $(R, \mathfrak m, \kappa= R/\mathfrak m )$ be a local ring with max ideal $m$.

We can obtain two new rings $R^h$ (the Henselization) and $\widehat{R}_m$ the completion wrt $m$. Consider $R$ as a stalk of a nice enough scheme $S$ we can use these two constructions to obtain new new objects stalkwise: $S^h$ (here we have to differ between strict and "weak" Henselization) and the completion $\widehat{S}$. (recall $\widehat{S}$ is not more a scheme but a ringed space: localizations and completions not behave well to each other).

I would like to compare the main differences & (dis)advantages of completions & Henselizations from viewpoint of commutative algebra and (as well possible) geometric intuition.

The main motivation is that I often read comments like "in practice it's often nicer to work with Henselizations than with completions" in order to study the ring $R$ itself.

*Question*: Could anybody point out what are the advantages making Henselizations from certain viewpoint nicer to handle with then with completions?

In many comments the hand wavy arguments appearing in this context are like $\widehat{R}_m$ is much "bigger" that $R^h$ making it not "so easy handable like $R^h$". Could anybody bring more light in this formulation? When is mean by "bigger" (the added limits of Cauchy sequences I guess) but much more interesting what makes $R^h$ more "handable"?

The only point that I found out is that $Frac(R)=K \subset K^h$ stays algebraic and in many situations even finite. Is $R \to R^h$ also a finite $R$-module. In general that's not true for completions $ R \to \widehat{R}_m$.

Is this the *only* point making $R^h$ more handable than $ R \to \widehat{R}_m$?

What can we say about the geometrical part? The completion $\widehat{S}$ gives in certain way "analytic structure" to an (algebraic) scheme $S$ (very hand wavy; I know). About what kind of "geometry" one can think when one consider a henselization of a scheme (as for completion: local ring wise)? Some sources refer to "etale topology". It's a starting point of a huge machinery cumulating in stack theory.

Is there a geometric intuition how one can draw comparisons between endowings of $S$ "analytical structure" (as for completions) and with "etale topology" for $S^h$?

I know that there are a couple of questions here with similar titles (eg https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105381/henselization-and-completion , https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133499/completion-versus-henselization , https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217540/comparison-of-completion-and-henselization-in-class-field-theory ) but none of them deal with question of pure comparison of two constructions in the way I explained above.

Rmk: This is exactly the same [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354646/henselization-and-completions-of-local-rings-schemes) I asked some days ago in MO.

Comment: Again look at $\Bbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$ as I did in your other questions. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565898/algebraic-closure-of-kt
At first $R$ is a DVR, $K=Frac(R)$, $K_v$ is the completion, $\overline{K}$ is the algebraic closure, and $K_h=K_v\cap \overline{K}$. The next step is to generalize to $\Bbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ a local ring of dimension $2$. The completion is a ring of formal power series whereas the Hensalization is a subring which is in the same time a ring of algebraic functions with formal power series expansion at almost every primes.

Comment: In some cases, there is no "the completion" at all, in the sense that two maximal immediate extensions may not be isomorphic over the valued field. (if by completion you mean the maximal dense extension in the valuation topology, then it does not contain the henselization in general). The henselization has the initial property among henselian extensions which makes it easy to use also when dealing with various embeddings.

Comment: @reuns: In your argument you use the identity $K_h=K_v\cap \overline{K}$.
Do you know if there exist a quick argument why this identity holds or
is it really a "deep" result. Meanwhile nombre gave here 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354591/henselian-valued-fields-for-characteristic-0-a-characterization?noredirect=1#comment889599_354591
an excellent reference where the proof of this identity is explained
but I saw in a couple of your answers that you using frequently this 
identity and I'm asking if you possibly know an "ad hoc" argument why 
this holds?

Comment: @nombre: I was talking indeed about this completion with resp the maximal ideal $m$.
And you claim that in general the henselization is not contained in the 
completion. Do you have a conterexample? But at least there always exist
a map $R^h \to \widehat{R}_m$ since $\widehat{R}_m$ has Hensel property
and $R^h$ has universal property that every map $R \to T$ where $T$ has 
Hensel property, factorizes through $R^h$, right?

Comment: Additionally, you wrote "... henselization has the initial property 
among henselian extensions which makes it easy to use..."

By "initial property" I guess you mean exactly the universal property
I explaned above? Could you loose a couple of works on what you concretly
mean by "makes it easy to use"? I think this is exactly the core
of my question: it is often mentioned that the henselization is 
"easier to handle" but I not understand in concrete which way.

Comment: I take it as the definition for DVR then prove a smaller field won't satisfy Hensel's lemma. I didn't investigate much the difficulties in a larger number of variables or with non-discrete valuations.

Comment: @reuns:Wait, wait. You claim that there is definition of a DVR such that a ring 
$R$ is DVR iff $K_h=K_v\cap \overline{K}$ for $K=Frac(R)$?

Comment: Maybe our frameworks are different. The completion (basically set of limits of Cauchy sequences) always has a similar universal (yes, the same as what I call initial) property as the henselization. If the valuation is discrete, then the completion contains the henselization in a unique way as per the henselization's initial property. If the valuation is not discrete, then this fails in general, i.e. the completion may not be Henselian.

Comment: @nombre: I see my thinking error. I was thinking the whole time only about the discrete valuation case where the completion has always Hensel property. Ok, if we focus only on this case (that is completions contains henselization), what is the advantage "to work with" henselization instead of the whole completion? Intuitively it's "smaller" since not contains all the added limits of Cauchy sequences. What I'm looking for are "properties of henselization that can be exploited" which the completion in general not have.

Comment: One important point was that heselization is a finite extension. Is this essentially the only one?

Comment: I don't know much about the use of henselizations in geometry. Of course the henselization is algebraic so it plays a role in algebraic geometry. For instance the Newton polygon method can be used to solve certain algebraic equations in the henselization. From a model-theoretic standpoint, some formulations of Hensel's property are first order. I don't think the henselization of a discrete valued field is a finite extension in general.

Comment: ups, I meant it's algebraic extension

Answer (score 1):

I can try to give a basic answer regarding the notion of "size". Henselization is a separable-algebraic extension, whereas completion need not be algebraic. For example, the completion of the rational function field $k(t)$ with respect to the $t$-adic valuation is the power series field $k((t))$. The transcendence degree of $k((t))/k(t)$ is uncountable.