# Galois Theory of Ramified Coverings & Classical Galois Theory

Tags: galois-theory, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces, galois-connections

The question adresses the answer in this thread:   [Algebraic closure of $k((t))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565898/algebraic-closure-of-kt?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In the answer reuns used a theory relating classical Galois theory with Galois theory of ramified coverings. I'm an absolute newbie in this area, so sorry if it's to simple. What I understand:

In this case we consider a finite Galois extension $L/\Bbb{C}(z)$. To field $L$ the theory says that one can associate a unique connected Riemann surface $Y_L$ and a map $f_L: Y_L \to \Bbb{PC^1}$ which is a ramified cover over $\Bbb{PC^1}$ of degree $n=[L:\Bbb{C}(z)]$.

Ramified means that that there exist a  finite subset $S \subset \Bbb{PC^1}$ (= the "branch points")  such that the restricted map $Y_L \backslash  f_L^{-1}(S) \to \Bbb{PC^1} \backslash S$ is a $n$-cover known from basic topology.

We recover $L$ as meromorphic functions on $Y_L$ (and $\Bbb{C}(z)$ " $\Bbb{PC^1}$).

The deepth of the theory gives a beautiful identification for Galois group  $$Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z))= \pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1} \backslash S,z_0)/Q$$

where $\pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1} \backslash S,z_0)$ is the fundamental group and the subgroup $Q \subset  \pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S,z_0)$ corresponds via classical covering theory to the cover $p:U_{\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S} \to Y_L \backslash  f_L^{-1}(S)$. Here $U_{\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S}$ is the universal cover of $\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S$. That's the background.

Two questions:

reuns wrote:

> For $L/\Bbb{C}(z)$ a finite Galois extension then its elements are locally meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}$ minus a few branch points (the zeros of the discriminant of the minimal polynomials) and $Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z))$ consists of the analytic continuations along closed loops enclosing some of those branch points.
>
> Proof: with $\gamma_1(a),\ldots,\gamma_m(a)$ the analytic continuations of $a$ then the coefficients of $h(X)=\prod_{l=1}^m(X-\gamma_m(a))$ stay the same under analytic continuation, thus they are meromorphic on the Riemann sphere, ie. they are in $\Bbb{C}(z)$ so $h(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$.

**QUESTION #1:**  I learned this theory from Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups". In the construction there wasn't explicitly explaned that the ramified points of $f$ correspond exacly to the zeros of the discriminant of minimal polynomial $F$ of the generator $g \in L$ (in case $L= \Bbb{C}(z)(g)$, otherwise consider minpolys of all generators).

Does anybody know literature explaning this construction of $Y_L$ from $L$ where is explicitly explaned why the branch points are exactly the zeros of the discriminant of minimal polynomials.

**QUESTION #2:**

How a $l \in \pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S,z_0)$ represents
an element of the Galois group $Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z))$.
Szmuely's book proof's the isomorphism
$\pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S,z_0)/Q= Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z))$
but unfortunately the proof not gives a good geometric
inside look what is going on there explicitely. In other words I "understand"
the proof but have no visual intuition on this identification.

What we need is that such $l$ act as automorphism on
the meromorphic function from $L$ and fixes $\Bbb{C}(z)$.

Reuns explaned this identification as
" analytic continuations along closed loops enclosing some of
those branch points."

I would like to understand what he means here. ie wlog say our
$l$ is a class of such closed loop around a pranch point.
What/ which object is here "analytically continued along $l$"?
How this construction works. The object of our interest
is the meromorphic function $m \in L$ of $Y_L$.

How it can be "continued"? Isn't it already determined
at a dense open subset of $Y_L$ exept at it's poles.
Thus why and how it is continued along $l$? I not
understand it.

Comment: Outside of the zeros/poles of the discriminant there are no branch points (it is easy to show that a solution of $P(z,s(z))= 0$ is locally unique/continuous/holomorphic/analytic away from the finitely many zeros/poles of $Disc(P(z,T))\in \Bbb{C}(z)$). It is untrue that a zero of $Disc(P(z,T))$ has to be a branch point, we need to check all the generators of the extension, similar to $\Bbb{Z}[3i]$ being ramified at $(3)$ whereas $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is not.

Comment: 1. The idea is this: given a curve $X$ and a finite extension $L$ of $K=k(X)$, then $L=K(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in L$ by the primitive elt theorem. The curve $Y$ corresponding to $L$ is the total space (``etale space'') of the sheaf of solutions to the minimal polynomial $m(x,\alpha)$ of $\alpha$ (more or less, this gives you a singular curve with singularities above the points $x$ where $m(x)$ has multiple roots).

Comment: 2. It's better if you think of $\pi_1$ in terms of deck transformations. The quotient of $\pi_1$ you wrote is the deck transforms of $Y\to X$ (after removing singular points to make it a covering map), so you need to show that a deck transform of $Y/X$ is the same thing as an automorphsm of $k(Y)/k(X)$. You can do this explicitly, but the better way of viewing things is that $\eta=\text{Spec}k(Y)$ is the generic point of $Y$, so a map $k(Y)\to k(Y)$ gives $\eta\to\eta\hookrightarrow Y$, which extends to all of $Y$ (special fact about smooth curves, a partially-defined map between smooth...

Comment: ...curves always extends to a map between the smooth curves.